# Javascript: Why a date does not return the right day?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm from Brazil and I've written this piece of code in Javascript

```
var dt = new Date(2012,9,21);   // Oct-21-2012
alert(dt.getDate());
```

However, it produces 20 and not 21. I've tested with Firefox 18, Chrome 24 and Internet Explorer 8.

How it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You came across a huge coincidence.

In Brazil, Oct-21-2012 is the start of daylight saving time in most of the country, so local dates at Oct-21-2012 between 0:0 and 1:0 doesn't exist in Brazil!

Some people from other countries did not face the same problem in the same date.

See: http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/brazil-dst-2012.html

In Brazil the code inside the question really outputs 20

```
var dt = new Date(2012,9,21);  // 21-Oct-2012 0:0
alert(dt.getDate());
```

However, a slight change generates 21, because 1 hour is enough to "jump over" the lost hour:

```
var dt = new Date(2012,9,21,1);  // 21-Oct-2012 1:00
alert(dt.getDate());
```

See: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2013.html

**Edit after comments:** In United States, for instance, at 10 March, 2013 will start the daylight saving time.

```
var dt = new Date(2013,02,10);  // March-10-2013
alert(dt.getDate());    // Output: 10
```

Why it is right? Because in the USA the daylight saving time jumps at 2:00 and not 0:00 like in Brazil, therefore implicit 0 hour protect the generated date against problems.However, it is still possible errors in hours elapsing calculation.
**-/-**

In Brazil the situation should to induce a bug in many sites that handle with dates, regardless of time. One can enter a date in a form and the algorithm calculating elapsed days in a wrong way.

For instance, if somebody uses this nice javascript code to enter dates in a form (
[DHML Goodies Calendar](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?page=calendarScripts) ), and after one decides to save that date in a database, it is possible that one get the wrong date, if one has a bad luck to meet special dates.

The definitive solution is use UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) time, because there is no Daylight Saving changes and you use a kind of abstract time. In most practical applications there is no problem.

```
var dt = new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 9, 21, 8, 5, 12));
alert( (dt.getUTCMonth()+1) + '/' + dt.getUTCDate() + '/' + 
        dt.getUTCFullYear() + " " + dt.getUTCHours()+ ':' + 
        dt.getUTCMinutes() + ':' + dt.getUTCSeconds() );
```

Instead of using UTC, it is easier, if someone doesn't use hours, minutes and seconds, just put a dummy hour value greater or equal than 1, as I have shown above, in Date() call.

**Edit after comments:** So the Brazil (and countries like Iran,Lebanon, Paraguay, Chile and Portugal ) should change the start of daylight saving time to 2:00 and not 0:00, in order to avoid this confusion and get aligned to more developed countries.
**-/-**

Comment: Can you really use new date() like that?

Comment: out of curiosity, do browsers have db to track daylight savings changes? If not how does Date object stay current?

Comment: @kennebeck, Date.UTC return miliseconds since Jan,1,1900 and new Date has a miliseconds elapsed option.

Comment: `new date(2013,03,10);` will be **April**, not March.

Comment: @charlietfl, that is a good point. I really don't know. The Daylight Saving time just finished in Brazil and I will test it and post the comments here.

Comment: @charlietfl–Date objects have a [time value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) that is used to create a local time based on the system clock. So if the host's clock is set correctly, it all works. If not, it doesn't.

Comment: @RobG  understood but does the OS provide data for daylight savings? If the calcs get thrown off when you are within that one hour of the change, Date object has to know somehow

Comment: BTW, the issue is unique to places where daylight saving starts at midnight (0000). Most places change the time at 0200 to avoid the issue.

Comment: @charlietfl–The OS just provides a timezone offset to use for `getFullYear`, `getMoth`, etc. and data to create a time value when creating a date object. A date object just has a time value (ms since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) and an offset in minutes that is used by various methods to get local time and date values. So the date object itself has no idea about whether daylight saving applies or not.

Comment: @RobG, Cool! I didn't know that most places change the clock at 2:00.

Comment: @charlietfl, I've tested it. Obviously, a final of daylight saving time is not a problem because some hour exists 2 times.

Comment: I've researched and @RobG is right. Just Iran, Syria, Brazil, Lebanon, Greenland, Portugal, Chile and Paraguay forward 00:00 to 01:00 in the beginning of daylight saving time. In other countries, the kind of bug that I've described is not possible. (See http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2013a.html and http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2013b.html)